# Run cron at 7AM on multiple timezones

Tags: node.js, cron

I would like to run cron jobs when it is 7AM locally in Western US, Eastern US and some other timezones in Asia and Europe.

This is a node.js server, so I can probably use [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) to do this but I'd like to use the regular cron if it's at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Times in the `crontab` always refer to the current system time. You will have to subtract or add timezone differences to calculate the execution intervals on your server.

E.g.: 
Your server is in the Western US (UTC+8) and the system date is set to be UTC+8. 7am can be specified in `crontab` using

```
0 7 * * * /run/me-for-western-us
```

To run a script when it is 7 am in Eastern US (UTC+5), you need to subtract 3 hours

```
0 4 * * * /run/me-for-eastern-us
```

Do the same for all other timezones.

Comment: I forgot to mention that these cron jobs needs to be dynamically created as new locations are added. Your answer is correct though, just not what I have in mind. I guess I'll go with node-cron. Thx!

Comment: you could always use 0 * * * * /run/me and then let the script decide what to do based on a database of locations and time zones. Worst case, that script is called 24 times a day and won't do anything productive 15 to 20 of those times. Not too bad I'd say.